# multilinear transformation and derivatives question

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multilinear-algebra

Let $B ∈ \mathcal L^2(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ and $f (\mathbf x) = B(\mathbf x, \mathbf x)$. Show that $D f (\mathbf x_0)(\mathbf h) = B(\mathbf x_0, \mathbf h) + B(\mathbf h, \mathbf x_0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f=B\circ (id,id)$, so $Df(x) = DB(id(x),id(x)) \circ (D(id)(x), D(id)(x)) = DB(x,x) \circ (id,id)$.

Thus, $Df(x)h = DB(x,x)(h,h)$.

Recall that $DB(x,y)(h,k) = B(x,k) + B(h,y)$.

Comment: what is your id here?

Comment: and how do you know $DB(x,y)(h,k)=B(x,k)+B(h,y)$?

Comment: @R.T. $id$ is the identity. For your second question, you can readily verify that.

Comment: Yeah, but what identity?

Comment: @R.T. assuming that by $\mathcal{L}^2(R^n,R^m)$ you mean the space of all bilinear functions $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, it's the identity of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: If I try to evaluate the derivative by using $f(x+h)-f(x)$, do you know how can I show $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\|B(h,h)\|}{\|h\|}=0$? Thanks.

Comment: @R.T. we have $\|B(h,h)\| \le \|B\| \|h\|^2$; in general one has $\|B(x,y)\| \le \|B\|\|x\|\|y\|$.